# Java Byte Array conversion Issue

Tags: java

I have a string which contains a series of bits (like "01100011") and some Integers in a while loop. For example:

```
while (true) {
    int i = 100;
    String str = Input Series of bits

    // Convert i and str to byte array
}
```

Now I want a nice fastest way to convert string and int to byte array. Until now, what I have done is convert `int` to `String` and then apply the `getBytes()` method on both strings. However, it is little bit slow. Is there any other way to do that which is (may be) faster than that?

Comment: what is the relation between `i` and `str`?

Comment: @dash1e, no relation. I just show an example. i and str are different. str is not i 's bit representation.

Comment: So you need two separate and fast function to convert intengers or bit string in byte array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Java ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class!

Example

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(1000).array();
```

Comment: Is this available in java inbuilt packages ?

Answer (score 2):

Converting an int is easy (little endian):

```
byte[] a = new byte[4];
a[0] = (byte)i;
a[1] = (byte)(i >> 8);
a[2] = (byte)(i >> 16);
a[3] = (byte)(i >> 24);
```

Converting the string, first convert to integer with `Integer.parseInt(s, 2)`, then do the above.  Use `Long` if your bitstring may be up to 64 bits, and `BigInteger` if it will be even bigger than that.

Answer (score 1):

For int

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int i) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(i >>> 24),
            (byte)(i >>> 16),
            (byte)(i >>> 8),
            (byte)i};
}
```

For string

```
byte[] buf = intToByteArray(Integer.parseInt(str, 2))
```

Comment: The string can contain at most 32 bits (without leading zeros). And you need to put it in a byte array, so that's wrong

Comment: Ok, you need to process 8 bit per 8 bit, or reuse `intToByteArray`.